# Magento categories are not being displayed.

Tags: php, magento

In **my-theme/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml** here is code for listing of all categories and its respective sub-categories and its working correctly. Here is code of left.phtml file

```
    <?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
   <?php if($_menu): ?>
   <ul ><?php echo $_menu ?>
   <ul>
   <?php endif ?>
```

I found  renderCategoriesMenuHtml() function in **app / code / core / Mage / Catalog / Block/navigation.php** here is code of **navigation.php** file

```
    class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
     {
   protected $_categoryInstance = null;

/**
 * Current category key
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_currentCategoryKey;

/**
 * Array of level position counters
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_itemLevelPositions = array();

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => false,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG),
    ));
}

/**
 * Get Key pieces for caching block content
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $shortCacheId = array(
        'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
        'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
        'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
        $this->getCurrenCategoryKey()
    );
    $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

    $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

    $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
    $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

    return $cacheId;
}

/**
 * Get current category key
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCurrenCategoryKey()
{
    if (!$this->_currentCategoryKey) {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($category) {
            $this->_currentCategoryKey = $category->getPath();
        } else {
            $this->_currentCategoryKey = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
    }

    return $this->_currentCategoryKey;
}

/**
 * Get catagories of current store
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
 */
public function getStoreCategories()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    return $helper->getStoreCategories();
}

/**
 * Retrieve child categories of current category
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
 */
public function getCurrentChildCategories()
{
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
    $productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);
    return $categories;
}

/**
 * Checkin activity of category
 *
 * @param   Varien_Object $category
 * @return  bool
 */
public function isCategoryActive($category)
{
    if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
        return in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds());
    }
    return false;
}

protected function _getCategoryInstance()
{
    if (is_null($this->_categoryInstance)) {
        $this->_categoryInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    }
    return $this->_categoryInstance;
}

/**
 * Get url for category data
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategoryUrl($category)
{
    if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
        $url = $category->getUrl();
    } else {
        $url = $this->_getCategoryInstance()
            ->setData($category->getData())
            ->getUrl();
    }

    return $url;
}

/**
 * Return item position representation in menu tree
 *
 * @param int $level
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getItemPosition($level)
{
    if ($level == 0) {
        $zeroLevelPosition = isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]) ? $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] + 1 : 1;
        $this->_itemLevelPositions = array();
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = $zeroLevelPosition;
    } elseif (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level])) {
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]++;
    } else {
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = 1;
    }

    $position = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= $level; $i++) {
        if (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$i])) {
            $position[] = $this->_itemLevelPositions[$i];
        }
    }
    return implode('-', $position);
}

/**
 * Render category to html
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @param int Nesting level number
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
 * @return string
 */
protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
    $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
{
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = array();

    // get all children
    if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    } else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
    $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

    // select active children
    $activeChildren = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
    $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

    // prepare list item html classes
    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    // prepare list item attributes
    $attributes = array();
    if (count($classes) > 0) {
        $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
         $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
         $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
    }

    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';

    // render children
    $htmlChildren = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
            $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $child,
            ($level + 1),
            ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            false,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $noEventAttributes
        );
        $j++;

    }
    if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        }
       $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
        $html[] = $htmlChildren;
        $html[] = '</ul>';

        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    $html[] = '</li>';

    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Render category to html
 *
 * @deprecated deprecated after 1.4
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @param int Nesting level number
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
 * @return string
 */
public function drawItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
{
    return $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level, $last);
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
 */
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')) {
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentCategoryPath()
{
    if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
        return explode(',', $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathInStore());
    }
    return array();
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @return string
 */
public function drawOpenCategoryItem($category) {
    $html = '';
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $html.= '<li';

    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $html.= ' class="active"';
    }

    $html.= '>'."\n";
    $html.= '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"><span>'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'</span></a>'."\n";

    if (in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategoryPath())){
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $hasChildren = $children && $children->count();

        if ($hasChildren) {
            $htmlChildren = '';
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $htmlChildren.= $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($child);
            }

            if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
                $html.= '<ul>'."\n"
                        .$htmlChildren
                        .'</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html.= '</li>'."\n";
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Render categories menu in HTML
 *
 * @param int Level number for list item class to start from
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @return string
 */
public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    $activeCategories = array();
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
    $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

    if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
        $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $category,
            $level,
            ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            true,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            true
        );
        $j++;
    }

    return $html;
}

 }
```

Now. I have created a new file template to list all categories and its subcategories at location **my-theme/template/catalog/navigation/all_cat.phtml**  and I pasted the code of **left.phtml** file into **all_cat.phtml** file. 
But when I'm executing this file on fronted I could not see any such categories and subcategories in **all_cat.phtml** file. I dont know what I'm missing and How to correct it. So please someone help me to find it out !

Comment: let me give the code of the all_cat.phtml and did you setTemplate this file in layout xml???

Comment: I have created a cms page and in the content section i called that block by {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/navigation/all_cat.phtml"}}

Comment: Please try my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.nav" template="catalog/navigation/all_cat.phtml"}}
```

Comment: hey wow it works thank you so much ..I can see all the categories and its subcategories. But its not that much understandable which is main categories and which is its subcategories because it just providing a plain list

Comment: Yes @user3611515 . Happy programming :) contact back if you want further help.

Comment: yeah sure @ Chiragit007